# What does The Butlerian Jihad's coverart depict?

Tags: dune, cover-art, brian-herbert

The first book of *Dune*'s prequel series depicts a sand worm, a classic motif of the *Dune* books. After reading the book, one thing kept bothering me.

***What is the object in the mouth of the sand worm?***

Here is a close up of it: [image]

It seems as though it may be the probe that Omnius dispatched to Arrakis, but the book mentioned nothing about the probe retaliating to the worm with its defenses.

Comment: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VEWOeuEFByY/VGa_rDxmvrI/AAAAAAAADAA/BE9uCDhH2xU/s1600/9b-The-Butlerian-Jihad.jpg - Stephen Youll

Comment: http://www.stephenyoull.com/stephenyoull.com/Butlerian_Jihad.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It certainly appears to be Omnius' probe. Note that it did get off a few shots and although there's no indication in the book that they hit, [book covers](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/CoversAlwaysLie/Literature) are notorious for [not being wholly accurate](http://i.crackedcdn.com/phpimages/article/5/2/7/219527_v1.jpg)...

> The crashed probe continued its pounding, rhythmic motion with a clattering of components, oblivious to its surroundings. **The assembled mechanism raised itself, a monstrous composite of crystalline materials and silica struts reinforced by carbon-fiber beams converted from its own hull and support girders.**
>
> The sandworm came in fast, tunneling just beneath the surface until its head rose up. The mouth was a huge shovel larger than the impact crater.
>
> The robotic probe waved its sensor arms and weapons lenses, sensing it was being attacked, but not understanding how. **Several white-hot blasts of fire penetrated the loose ground.**
>
> The worm swallowed the mechanical demon whole. Then the sinuous desert creature burrowed beneath the dust again like a sea serpent seeking deeper waters…